# Editing sass in server

Tags: css, sass

I want to edit something in my SASS files which are uploaded to the server. How can I make watch SASS to CSS files on command line?

Comment: Do you have `libsass` or `Ruby Sass` installed on the server?

Comment: I have installed `sass` on my computer but not on server

Comment: I do not recommend to edit something on your server. Edit it on your development computer, check the result, then upload it to server once again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use grunt. Run a grunt watcher on the server. 
https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-sass (Install grunt using npm)

When you run the watcher, the css file will be updated as you save the sass.

Comment: This method requires to have `node`, `libsass` or `Ruby Sass`, `grunt` and `grunt-sass` or `grunt-contrib-sass` and `grunt-contrib-watch`. A lot of dependencies just for one edit!

Comment: Ok I will try to use one of these methods. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Sass on your server, just like you did on your local machine. Than enter the sass commands on the server console.

Comment: I searched but didn't find the way to install `sass` on server. How can i do this?

Comment: Do you have access to the server's console?

for linux server:
1) Install ruby: `sudo apt-get install ruby-full rubygems`
2) Install sass: `sudo gem install sass`